# Creating List Like Array with Dynamic Memory Management

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

There are a lecture class and student class. We are trying to save student information on lecture class with arrays.

For example:

```
Student * studentList = new Student[numberOfStudent];
studentAdd("Mary");
studentDelete("Mary");
```

Problem:
User is not giving number of student and number of student is increasing when user add a new one with a one of lecture method. So I think that i need a list like structer to save them but it is forbidden for this work. Do you have any efficient ideas than my temporary solution?

My temporary solution:
Saving number of student and array size and when number of student is more than size copy array to a new one which is bigger than old one.

This question is related to my assigment which we are forcing to this by

*using dynamically allocated memory using pointers

*without using any static arrays with fixed sizes or other data structures such as
vector from the standard library

Comment: basically they want you to make your own impl of vector class?

Comment: If this is an assignment given to new C++ students, no wonder Java gains more new fans.  It's the way that C++ is taught these days that's making this happen.

Comment: I search on web and see that yes they probably want this. However I can't find any faster solution then my slow solution.

Comment: @orcungumus - the more efficient solution is to allocate more than what is necessary (a capacity).  For example, if the number of students is 100, then allocate memory for 250 or 300 students (allocate memory, do *not* create 250 / 300 students).

Comment: @orcungumus - so you can't create your own class to do this?  If you can create your own class, then have two member variables -- one to keep track of the actual number of students, and another to keep track of the maximum capacity.  Then work it out from there as to when to allocate more memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes thank you, i will apply these suggestion. My temporary solution is what you say in second comment.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use functions if you don't want to use objects. Note that I haven't compiled this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

void add(Student **list, Student *rhs);
void destroy(Student **list,int const &idx);
void destroy(Student **list,const char* student_name); //find the student name and delete
void resize(Student **list,int const &idx);
Student** begin(Student **list,); //get the first Student
Student** end(Student **list,); //the end of the array
void clear(Student **list,); //drop all Students

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    stc::cerr << "not enough parameters" << std::endl;
  } 
  istringstream buffer(argv[1]);
  int value;
  buffer >> value; 
  Student ** studentList = new *Student[value];
  int s
  add(studentList, "Mary");
  destroy(studentList, "Mary");
  return(0);
}

void add(Student **list, Student *rhs) { /*definition*/ }
void destroy(Student **list, int const &idx) { /*definition*/ }
void destroy(Student **list, const char* student_name) { /*definition*/ }
void resize(Student **list, int const &idx) { /*definition*/ }
Student** begin(Student **list) { /*definition*/ }
Student** end(Student **list) { /*definition*/ }
void clear(Student **list) { /*definition*/ }
```

Now just define all that and you are all set

#### I do not recommend this approach

I would use objects... and taking into account what PaulMcKenzie said about capacity

```
class StudentList
{
private:
  Student **list;
  std::size_t size;
  std::size_t capacity;
public:
  StudentList(){}
  ~StudentList(){ this->clear(); }
  inline void add(Student *rhs) { //definition }
  inline void destroy(int const &idx) { //definition }
  inline void destroy(const char* student_name) { //definition }
  inline void resize(int const &idx) { //definition }
  inline Student** begin() { //definition }
  inline Student** end() { //definition }
  inline void clear() { //definition }
};
```

And if possible

### Iterators

Underneath vector you will find a similar implementation, it uses **Iterators** to encapsulate the `Student**`.

Comment: I can't understand this answer. It seen like you are also using  numberOfStudent varient which is not provited by user. You have resize method but i'm also curious about the inside of resize?

Why I store array of array for studentList?

Comment: btw, the questions that you are may seem confusing right now. But those functions are the usual functionality of a standard container.